# Draw sth. like rectangles inside a CameraPreview (SurfaceView)

Tags: android, preview, surfaceview

How can I draw for example a rectangle inside a CameraPreview (SurfaceView)?
In setPreviewCallback I've implement the invalidate method which should call the onDraw method. But nothing happened. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer my own question.
I've created a new class which extends the class View. In it I implemented the part of canvas object and the onDraw method. After this, I created an Object in the main Activity from the Type of the new class. With the method addContentView(View v, LayoutParam...) i have added the new View.
That was it. The new created View will be drawn over the SurfaceView now.

Hope this will help other people, who have the same problem.